# EL: cannot access property method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have my database whit a BLOB field named 'avatar' in which I store the user's photo. This field is represented in my JPA entity as a byte[]. I want to render the 'avatar' element only if the array has a positive length, but i get the next exception from javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter() :

"Exception: Method length not found"

This is the code:

```
<o:graphicImage id="avatar" 
                value="#{loginView.user.avatar}" 
                dataURI="true"
                rendered="#{loginView.user.avatar.length()>0}"
 />
```

If I check the length from the backing bean, returning a Boolean to the EL, it works and renders the image, but I need to preserve the backing code unaltered, that's why I need to do the checking from my xhtml.
Thanks.

**edit**:  rendered="#{not empty loginView.user.avatar}" is not working, that's why I had to move to another option.

Comment: how about 'loginView.user.avatar.length() gt 0'?

Comment: How exactly does *"rendered="#{not empty loginView.user.avatar}" is not working"* not work? This is the correct approach. Perhaps you're incorrectly throwing an exception inside `getAvatar()` instead of just returning `null`?

Comment: The getAvatar() method is just an auto-generated method from an entity created with Netbeans wizard from the table... it just returns a byte[], pretty simple... What puzzles me is that it works in another project just as you suggest, but for this project I had to relax the constraints and move on with an idea very similar to the one provided by Krzysztof. I cannot see any difference though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSTL. Taglib namespace:

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
```

Usage:

```
<o:graphicImage id="avatar" 
            value="#{loginView.user.avatar}" 
            dataURI="true"
            rendered="#{fn:length(loginView.user.avatar) > 0}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Length is not a method but property of array. Try to make a method inside loginView bean which will return something like this.

```
public boolean isAvatarLoaded() {
    return this.user.avatar.length > 0;
}

<o:graphicImage id="avatar" 
                value="#{loginView.user.avatar}" 
                dataURI="true"
                rendered="#{loginView.isAvatarLoaded()}"
 />
```

Comment: As I mention at the end of the post, I tried your suggestion, but it's a requirement to not alter the code in loginView. Thanks any way for the clarification about length().